# Can't start OrientDB Server

Tags: orientdb

I installed OrientDB 2.2.0 on my server but can't start it running server.sh script. Previous version started fine on the server and the current version is running on my notebook. The server is a droplet from Digital Ocean with Ubuntu 15.10 32-bit. The error I get is below.

> Invalid maximum direct memory size: -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=512g The
>   specified size exceeds the maximum representable size. Error: Could
>   not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception has
>   occurred. Program will exit.

**Update**
The problem was with -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=512g. I changed it to -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=512m and the error disappeared. The problem now is that the server tries to start but gives me the message below:

> Creating the system database 'OSystem' for current server
>   [OSystemDatabase]Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory
>           at java.nio.Bits.reserveMemory(Bits.java:693)
>           at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.(DirectByteBuffer.java:123)
>           at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(ByteBuffer.java:311)
>           at com.orientechnologies.common.directmemory.OByteBufferPool.allocateBuffer(OByteBufferPool.java:309)
>           at com.orientechnologies.common.directmemory.OByteBufferPool.acquireDirect(OByteBufferPool.java:228)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.cache.local.OWOWCache.cacheFileContent(OWOWCache.java:1255)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.cache.local.OWOWCache.load(OWOWCache.java:617)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.cache.local.twoq.O2QCache.updateCache(O2QCache.java:1200)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.cache.local.twoq.O2QCache.doLoad(O2QCache.java:439)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.cache.local.twoq.O2QCache.allocateNewPage(O2QCache.java:489)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.atomicoperations.OAtomicOperation.commitChanges(OAtomicOperation.java:426)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.atomicoperations.OAtomicOperationsManager.endAtomicOperation(OAtomicOperationsManager.java:420)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.base.ODurableComponent.endAtomicOperation(ODurableComponent.java:118)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OPaginatedCluster.create(OPaginatedCluster.java:197)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.addClusterInternal(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:3349)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.doAddCluster(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:3330)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.create(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:381)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage.create(OLocalPaginatedStorage.java:120)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.create(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:378)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OSystemDatabase.init(OSystemDatabase.java:106)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OSystemDatabase.(OSystemDatabase.java:42)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.initSystemDatabase(OServer.java:1217)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.activate(OServer.java:343)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServerMain.main(OServerMain.java:41)

Comment: Hi @Paulo it's seems that the memory settings is wrong. which is the value of your XX:MaxDirectMemorySize?

Comment: @MichelaBonizzi  Where can I see it? Sorry for my newbie question

Comment: you have to open the server.sh

Comment: @MichelaBonizzi It was -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=512g. I changed to  -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=512m but now I get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory

Comment: Done! I chamged the value to 128m and OrientDB started fine. I don't understand. This is a test server with 8Gb.

Comment: Post an answer and accept it if the problem is solved, don't write it into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Everything is okay now. I just changed `-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=512m` to `-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=2g`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have 32-bit JVM. You should set this value to -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=2g .

Comment: I solved changing it to -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=128m

Comment: That is incorrect , as minimum you make all things slow.